# Where can I find a tar.gz of TightVNC for the Pi?

Tags: vnc

I currently have access via putty and WinSCP to my Pi over ethernet only. I want to install tightVNC so I can use the GUI but I don't have internet access on the Pi. I figured if I can find a tar.gz of TightVNC I can just drop it in via WinSCP then install it from the command line via Putty.

***Where can I find a zipped distro of TightVNC for the Pi?***

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to connect the PI to the internet for a few minutes and execute the following command but I assume there is a reason you have opted not to go that route.

```
apt-get install vnc-server
```

The VNC-Server software for Raspbian is located [here](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/t/tightvnc/). But note, it also depends on the following:

```
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.13-28), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libx11-6, 
         libxext6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), perl, x11-common | 
         xserver-common, x11-utils, xauth
Recommends: xfonts-base, x11-xserver-utils
```

You will have to grab those packages as well in order for it to install without any dependency issues. Consider connecting your PI directly and downloading via apt-get.

I found this information from the [Packages](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository) file on the website for Raspbian.

Comment: Yea definitely easiest to get internet access for a a few minutes, perform updates and install the latest packages needed for it. The OP must have internet somewhere since he posted the question :)